# How to Resolve EditText InputType Being Seen as Null Though it is Specified

Tags: android, android-edittext

Even though I have inputType specified for EditText fields, selecting the field causes the cursor to flash on screen and then disappear. The wrong keyboard is shown as well and logs indicate it thinks the inputType is null. Strangely, if I click on the field for half a second or so, it works as expected.

This is for entering data in to a form that get generated based on a JSON file. It was working without an issue previously, but broke somewhere along the way. Part of me wonders if this is an emulator bug as it seemed to start after updating the emulator. An example of the XML is outlined below. In this case it is for a number entry but it also impacts other inputTypes.

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:paddingStart="15dp"
    android:paddingEnd="15dp"
    android:paddingTop="15dp"
    android:paddingBottom="15dp"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal|numberSigned"
    android:background="@drawable/form_entry_text_back"
    android:id="@+id/number_entry"
    tools:ignore="Autofill,LabelFor" />
```

Expected:
Clicking on the field brings the field in to focus with a visible cursor. It also displays the correct keyboard type

Actual:
The auto complete UI above the keyboard flashes on screen briefly. The keyboard is shown but it isn't the correct type always. There is no cursor in the EditText field. Along with that, I get the following 3 log lines

```
01-19 11:41:38.300 1963-1963/com.android.inputmethod.latin I/LatinIME: Starting input. Cursor position = 0,0
01-19 11:41:38.377 1963-1963/com.android.inputmethod.latin I/LatinIME: Starting input. Cursor position = -1,-1
01-19 11:41:38.394 1963-1963/com.android.inputmethod.latin I/InputAttributes: InputType.TYPE_NULL is specified
```

Those are the only log lines shown

Workaround:
If I press and hold the click for just a little longer than normal, it works exactly as expected.

Comment: Any Java code affecting this EditText?

Comment: @TheWanderer yes. There is an addTextChanged listener added. However, if I remove that, the issue still happens.